# Outliers in data

Tags: pandas, statistics, median, outliers, standard-deviation

I have a dataset like so -

```
15643, 14087, 12020, 8402, 7875, 3250, 2688, 2654, 2501, 2482, 1246, 1214, 1171, 1165, 1048, 897, 849, 579, 382, 285, 222, 168, 115, 92, 71, 57, 56, 51, 47, 43, 40, 31, 29, 29, 29, 29, 28, 22, 20, 19, 18, 18, 17, 15, 14, 14, 12, 12, 11, 11, 10, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

Based on domain knowledge, I know that larger values are the only ones we want to include in our analysis. How do I determine where to cut off our analysis? Should it be don't include 15 and lower or 50 and lower etc?

Comment: I won't give a top-level answer as I don't know what the domain is, but I see that these are in descending order and that the difference between elements is never greater than 10 after the 26th element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a distribution check with quantile function. Then you can remove values below lowest 1 percentile or 2 percentile. Following is an example:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array(data)
print(np.quantile(data, (.01, .02)))
```

Another method is calculating the inter quartile range (IQR) and setting lowest bar for analysis is Q1-1.5*IQR

```
Q1, Q3 = np.quantile(data, (0.25, 0.75))
data_floor = Q1 - 1.5 * (Q3 - Q1)
```

Comment: I cannot use this because the `data_floor` value for the dataset in the question is `- 64.375` but there are no negative values and there will never be any negative values in this dataset.

Comment: Then you can use 1st one

Comment: Both the first and second percentiles are `1.0` because I have so many of them in my dataset.

Comment: If you already know the possible acceptable minimum value then why do you need to look at statistics???

Comment: I don't know the possible minimum value. I know it should be greater than 15 or something. `>1` does not seem correct.

Comment: If you know that it should be greater than 15 and also you want to use Statistical outlier detection then you can run any of the outlier detection processes after discarding all data below 15 by doing this: data <- data[data>15]